# Instagram Business Discovery API Videos thumbnail_url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

Instagram API endpoint for getting other business account media data

```
GET graph.facebook.com/VERSION/BUSINESS_ID?
    fields=business_discovery.username(bluebottle)
    {media{id,caption,media_type,media_url}}
```

It works great for getting Images and Videos URL.

But for getting Videos `thumbnail_url` ([REF](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media)), I have to modify it to

```
GET graph.facebook.com/VERSION/BUSINESS_ID?
    fields=business_discovery.username(bluebottle)
    {media{id,caption,media_type,media_url,thumbnail_url}}
```

And this query WILL FAIL as `thumbnail_url` is only available for media of type VIDEO

How can I get Videos `thumbnail_url`?

NOTE: If possible I want multiple Videos `thumbnail_url` with a single query. Eg. in Facebook API we can get it via (`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11?fields=full_picture&ids=ID1,ID2`)

Answer (score 0):

May be you use wrong token. `thumbnail_url` is not a public field,- it's available only for user that create this media.

Comment: It is not related to the token. By using the business_discovery functionality you can only query for public fields.